# MPDF - Start page numbering from number 10 on the first sheet

Tags: php, mpdf

I have an application and need to print a document using the MPDF class, however necessary that the number of page start at number 43, 44, 45 and so on.

And not from the 1, 2, 3 ...

I managed to start from the 43 but only jumping a leaf. I can not insert a pagebreak.

Thanks.

Below is my code.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->setFooter("{PAGENO}");

$numero_paginas = "{nb}";

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="img/cabecalho.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>
');

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('

<style type="text/css">
body{
    font-family:Arial, Times New Roman, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
}
</style>

' . $corpo_documento . '');

$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [mPDF manual on page numbers](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-numbering.html):

> If you want to set page numbering characteristics from the first page onwards, you should explicitly add the first page of the document using `AddPage()`. Note that this is normally not required, as mPDF creates a new first page automatically if required when first using `WriteHTML()`.

So, call `AddPage()` after setting the footer like this:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
$mpdf->AddPage('', '', 43);
```

Comment: OMG. You save my life. Thank you so much! Now another question '-' How can I capture in a variable number of the last page? {Nb} does not work here because it captures the actual amount of pages.

Comment: Use `$mpdf->docPageNum($mpdf->page);` or just `$mpdf->page + <initial page number>`

Comment: @Finwe I want to have the total page count to be printed inside the body. Is there any method or way available to retrieve that number?

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're adding a page by sending in an array of arguments, you can set it to 43 by setting `'resetpagenum' => '43'`

```
$mpdf->AddPageByArray([
    'margin-left' => '15mm',
    'margin-right' => '20mm',
    'margin-top' => '25mm',
    'margin-bottom' => '15mm',
    'resetpagenum' => '43'
]);
```